# how to synchronously push notification in foreground for android when I save the payload in async storage

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am new in react native push notification, I was having some trouble, so like there is two situation

1. If I send push notification by one, it can fetch the payload and save in async storage

Which is working for me.

2. If I send push notification multiple times, which is consistent of the time, it sometimes can save and sometimes cannot, which also lag the screen displaying the async storage

Which this is the problem, I wish to ask

RemotePushMessageController.js

```
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { saveAsyncStorage, getAsyncStorage } from "./asyncStorage";
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";

const RemotePushMessageController = () => {

  const handleOnNotification = async (notification) => {
      if (notification) {
        console.log("notification success", notification.data);

        const data = JSON.parse(await getAsyncStorage("@Messages"));
        const convertPayloadToJson = JSON.parse(await notification.data.payload);

          const saveNotificationPayload = {
            ...
            messageId: convertPayloadToJson.messageId,
            title: convertPayloadToJson.title,
            shortDescription: convertPayloadToJson.shortDescription,
            importance: convertPayloadToJson.importance,
          };
          data.push(saveNotificationPayload);

          await saveAsyncStorage("@Messages", JSON.stringify(data));
        }

        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      }
  };

  PushNotification.configure({
    // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
    onRegister: async function (token) {

    ...

    onNotification: handleOnNotification,

    senderID: "...",

    popInitialNotification: true,
    requestPermissions: true,

    permissions: {
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    },
  });
  return null;
};

export default RemotePushMessageController;
```

Which I have try, the response when sending multiple notification at the same time, it somehow did not finish the task and it skip to the next payload instead.

I have try researching about synchronously for iOS and I manage to do it but Android I did not know to do it, please some help...

For iOS I use APN and Android I use Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send it as object to redux, because every time the state is updated, the notifications will be updated.

Comment: I am not very sure what you mean, can you show me an example of how it was done? Sorry, I am not very good at redux.